# Remove and reload raster layer from previously created QgsRasterLayer object

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I have created a `QgsRasterLayer` object using:

```
lyr=QgsRasterLayer(url,'lyr_name')
```

and the layer is displayed by:

```
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

Now when this layer is removed through:

```
QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(lyr)
```

I am unable to reload it on the interface. I get below error:

```
RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of type QgsRasterLayer has been deleted
```

From what I understand the refrenced object of `lyr` is deleted.
I need a workaround for this so that I can load and unload `lyr` multiple times. Since the layer object is created dynamically for so recreating it is not an option.

Comment: your first line of code says `QgsVectorLayer(...)` - did you mean `QgsRasterLayer(...)`?

Comment: Yes I did.. I've edited the question